# For medicine we need a prescription; for having medical tests, what do we need?

Tags: single-word-requests

A prescription is a written order, especially by a physician, for the preparation and administration of a medicine or other treatment.
What do we call the written order the physician gives us, where he has written down what medical tests have to be run?

Comment: I think it's still a prescription.  For example, when I inquired about getting a mammogram from a local hospital, I was told that I needed a prescription.

Comment: @ andi, I guess you are right!!

Comment: Yes; certain tests require a physician's written order, while others are routine and don't. This is a good case for using etymology; _pre-scribe_ means 'write (it down) before(hand)'

Comment: A (completed) 'appointment form' is what I usually call what the doc gives me (for blood tests ...); I think he calls it that too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need a **doctor's order**.

Minor tests are ordered by prescription (e.g. a blood test, pulmonary function studies or a simple Xray). More complicated tests (multiple blood tests, scans, Xray series, etc.) are ticked off on an order form signed by the doctor or an assistant. The order is faxed over to the facility doing the test or taken there by the patient.

If the test must be scheduled, the assistant arranges it by phone, and faxes the order over. In that event, they still need a doctor's order.

That way, people cannot order unnecessary tests (many hypochondriacs or other people would), just as they can't prescribe their own medications.

Comment: This is consistent with the language used to describe the doctor's actions. We would say that the doctor "prescribes a drug" or "orders a test."

Comment: @chapka - the OP asked for a correlate to a *prescription* for *test*. The correlate is *a doctor's order*.

Comment: Yes, and I pointed out that this usage was consistent with the verbs we would use in the same situation. More pedantically, I might argue that the correlate for *prescription* is *order,* not *doctor's order.*

Comment: Medica, are you saying that a single test is always a prescription, and that more than one must be an order?

Comment: @Mitch - not quite. A prescription is usually for a medication. For tests, even if the request for the test is something quickly scribbled on a prescription pad (not done that way anymore), what you need is a doctor's order. It could be an order for an X-ray series, an MRI, labs, or physical therapy; it's still an order.

Answer (score 1):

In America, it is usually called a Lab Order; it is a somewhat standardized form, with checkboxes for various kinds of blood test, a space for any further instructions, and a line where the doctor signs it.

Comment: I agree in essence with this answer. Only because there are so many tests that a doctor can order, from a simple CBC with diff to a doppler ultrasound of arteries, to an MRI with contrast, I wouldn't restrict it to "lab order".